# Getting a really crypric message in react.js when changing routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, history

Upon changing my application route via history.replace(PATH), I get this really cryptic error message. The stack shows the error originating in redux's applyMiddleware. I use thunk and redux-promise for middleware.

I've tried tracing the rendering path through each of my components, and my breakpoint never gets to the render method of the state I'm trying to load.

I've also tried updating my npm modules and rebuilding the project.

I'm using React 15.0.2.

> ReactReconciler.js:54 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'getNativeNode' of null(…)getNativeNode @
>   ReactReconciler.js:54getNativeNode @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:303getNativeNode @
>   ReactReconciler.js:54updateChildren @
>   ReactChildReconciler.js:89_reconcilerUpdateChildren @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:178_updateChildren @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:271updateChildren @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:259_updateDOMChildren @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:845updateComponent @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:691receiveComponent @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:647ReactDOMComponent_receiveComponent @
>   ReactPerf.js:66receiveComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:103updateChildren
>   @ ReactChildReconciler.js:85_reconcilerUpdateChildren @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:178_updateChildren @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:271updateChildren @
>   ReactMultiChild.js:259_updateDOMChildren @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:845updateComponent @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:691receiveComponent @
>   ReactDOMComponent.js:647ReactDOMComponent_receiveComponent @
>   ReactPerf.js:66receiveComponent @
>   ReactReconciler.js:103_updateRenderedComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:661_performComponentUpdate @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:643updateComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:572ReactCompositeComponent_updateComponent
>   @ ReactPerf.js:66receiveComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:495receiveComponent @
>   ReactReconciler.js:103_updateRenderedComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:661_performComponentUpdate @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:643updateComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:572ReactCompositeComponent_updateComponent
>   @ ReactPerf.js:66receiveComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:495receiveComponent @
>   ReactReconciler.js:103_updateRenderedComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:661_performComponentUpdate @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:643updateComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:572ReactCompositeComponent_updateComponent
>   @ ReactPerf.js:66receiveComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:495receiveComponent @
>   ReactReconciler.js:103_updateRenderedComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:661_performComponentUpdate @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:643updateComponent @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:572ReactCompositeComponent_updateComponent
>   @ ReactPerf.js:66performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   ReactCompositeComponent.js:511performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   ReactReconciler.js:122runBatchedUpdates @ ReactUpdates.js:143perform @
>   Transaction.js:136perform @ Transaction.js:136perform @
>   ReactUpdates.js:89flushBatchedUpdates @
>   ReactUpdates.js:165ReactUpdates_flushBatchedUpdates @
>   ReactPerf.js:66closeAll @ Transaction.js:202perform @
>   Transaction.js:149batchedUpdates @
>   ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:63enqueueUpdate @
>   ReactUpdates.js:194enqueueUpdate @
>   ReactUpdateQueue.js:22enqueueSetState @
>   ReactUpdateQueue.js:201ReactComponent.setState @
>   ReactComponent.js:67handleChange @ connect.js:301dispatch @
>   createStore.js:186(anonymous function) @ index.js:28(anonymous
>   function) @ index.js:9dispatch @ applyMiddleware.js:45

Answer (score 5):

Solved the issue.  Turns out it was caused by attempting to map over an array to generate child components in the render method of the component navigated to. I wish the error message were a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Hi. What was the problem with mapping over and array? Was the array not defined or something? I'm getting the same error

Comment: So, what was the solution you came up with ?

Answer (score 0):

Also encountered this error. Just like *ThinkingInBits*, I was mapping over an array creating components. I made a change to the mapping function, leaving one of the variables `undefined`. This is the error that I kept getting and once I fixed the `undefined` variable issue, it disappeared. It is quite nasty in the way it is masking the actual problem.